# REST - What exactly is meant by Uniform Interface?

Tags: rest, definition, uniform-interface

[Wikipedia has:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Uniform_interface)

> **Uniform interface**
>
> The uniform interface constraint is fundamental to the design of any REST service.[14] The uniform interface simplifies and decouples the architecture, which enables each part to evolve independently. The four guiding principles of this interface are:
>
> **Identification of resources**
>
> Individual resources are identified in requests, for example using URIs in web-based REST systems. The resources themselves are conceptually separate from the representations that are returned to the client. For example, the server may send data from its database as HTML, XML or JSON, none of which are the server's internal representation, and it is the same one resource regardless.
>
> **Manipulation of resources through these representations**
>
> When a client holds a representation of a resource, including any metadata attached, it has enough information to modify or delete the resource.
>
> **Self-descriptive messages**
>
> Each message includes enough information to describe how to process the message. For example, which parser to invoke may be specified by an Internet media type (previously known as a MIME type). Responses also explicitly indicate their cacheability.
>
> **Hypermedia as the engine of application state (A.K.A. HATEOAS)**
>
> Clients make state transitions only through actions that are dynamically identified within hypermedia by the server (e.g., by hyperlinks within hypertext). Except for simple fixed entry points to the application, a client does not assume that any particular action is available for any particular resources beyond those described in representations previously received from the server.

I'm listening to a lecture on the subject and the lecturer has said:

> "When someone comes up to our API, if you are able to get a customer object and you know there are order objects, you should be able to get the order objects with the same pattern that you got the customer objects from. These URI's are going to look like each other."

**This strikes me as wrong.** It's not so much about what the URI's look like or that there is consistency as it is the way in which the URI's are used (identify resources, manipulate the resources through representations, self-descriptive messages, and hateoas).

I don't think that's what Uniform Interface means at all. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: I believe they mean that if you can get customer information through an endpoint routed as /api/customer then you could infer that to get order information you could do a request to /api/order

Comment: @vesuvious That's exactly what I mean. That's wrong. REST API's are discovery API's not inference API's. The client should make no inferences. If it does, the client and server are too tightly coupled.

Comment: @richard: I have never seen a discoverable REST API. Can you give an example?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not sure what you mean. REST API's are by definition discovery API's.

Comment: @Richard: then I guess I don't know what you mean by "discovery APIs", or else the "REST" APIs that I have used were not really REST APIs. There was no way to discover the API given a starting point, if that's what you mean by "discovery API".

Comment: I think you may be confusing REST and SOAP, as SOAP is often discoverable through the wsdl

Comment: Here is the REST spec..seems like people should be able to infer almost everything: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: @jon yes, that is what I mean by discovery api. If the api isn't using hypermedia as the engine of state, then it's not a restful api. That is my understanding. I'm trying to grok rest so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @vesuvius I don't think that's discovery. That's a contract laid out there that tightly couples client and server.

Comment: I'll shut up now, and just say, "Roy Fielding's New Clothes".

Comment: @jon I don't know what you mean. Your comments have been enigmatic. Am I being idiotic and have this whole thing completely wrong? I really am trying to understand this. If you don't know that's fine too.

Comment: Ok now I understand. You don't like rest?

Comment: The strict definition of RESTful architecture is that it must be discoverable...unfortunately the majority of APIs claim to be RESTful and fail this constraint.  In the real world many APIs that are not strictly RESTful are called REST, because they use HTTP and JSON or XML and sometimes have params in URLs and sometimes use HTTP Verbs/Methods.  Some people are using Hypermedia API as a term to indicate an API is truly RESTful.  to @JohnSaunders you should look at github's api to see a discoverable API

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using interfaces to decouple classes from the implementation of their dependencies is a pretty old concept. In REST you use the same concept to decouple the client from the implementation of the REST service. In order to define such an interface (a contract between the client and the service), you have to use standards. This is because if you want an internet size network of REST services, you have to enforce global concepts, like standards to make them understand each other.

- **Identification of resources** - You use the URI (IRI) standard to identify a resource. In this case, a resource is a web document.
- **Manipulation of resources through these representations** - You use the HTTP standard to describe communication. So for example GET means that you want to retrieve data about the URI-identified resource. You can describe an operation with an HTTP method and a URI.
- **Self-descriptive messages** - You use standard MIME types and (standard) [RDF vocabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/RDF) to make messages self-descriptive. So the client can find the data by checking the semantics, and it doesn't have to know the application-specific data structure the service uses.
- **Hypermedia as the engine of application state** (a.k.a. HATEOAS) - You use hyperlinks and possibly [URI templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_Template) to decouple the client from the application-specific URI structure. You can annotate these hyperlinks with semantics e.g. [IANA link relations](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), so the client will understand what they mean.

Comment: Nice Explanation in simple terms

Comment: Because it is simple. :-)

Comment: of course I've heard of interfaces and I'm clear on the concepts of decoupling implementation through contracts (interfaces). I think what I was missing was that Uniform Interface just meant those 4 constraints (identification of resources, manipulation through representations, self-descriptive messages, and hateos).

Comment: "You can describe an operation with a HTTP method and an URI." Only if the URI is HTML-based. (mailto's are URIs that are not HTML-based - they are mailto based.)

Comment: where is the Uniform Interface? You described other principles but asker looking for Uniform Interface...

Comment: @nuriselcuk These concepts are together the uniform interface.

Comment: Why you talk about Standars? Rest never talks about standars

Answer (score 15):

The **Uniform Interface** constraint (that any **ReSTful API** should comply with) suggests that server responses, in addition to containing data, should also announce available actions and resources.

In [chapter 5 ("Reprensational State Transfer")](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of his dissertation, [Roy Fielding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Fielding) states that the aim of using *uniform interfaces* is to:

> *ease and improve global architecture and the visibility of interactions*

In other words, **querying resources should allow the client to request other actions and resources without knowing them in advance**.

The **JSON-API** specs ([jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/)) offer a good example in the form of a JSON response to an (hypothetical) HTTP `GET` request on http://example.com/articles :

```json
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/articles",
    "next": "http://example.com/articles?page[offset]=2",
    "last": "http://example.com/articles?page[offset]=10"
  },
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
        },
      },
      "comments": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/comments",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/comments"
        }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/articles/1"
    }
  }]
}
```

Just by analysing this single response, a client knows:

1. **What entities** were queried ("articles" in this example);
2. **How these entities are structured** (articles have fields: `id`, `title`, `author`, `comments`);
3. **How to retrieve** related entities (i.e. the `author` and the `comments`);
4. That **there are more entities** of type "articles" (`10`, based on current response length and pagination links).

For those passionate about the topic, I strongly recommend reading [Roy Thomas Fielding's dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think I understand what it means.

From Fieldings dissertation:

> The central feature that distinguishes the REST architectural style from other network-based styles is its emphasis on a uniform interface between components (Figure 5-6). By applying the software engineering principle of generality to the component interface, the overall system architecture is simplified and the visibility of interactions is improved.

He's saying that the interface between components must be the same. Ie. between client and server and any intermediaries, all of which are components.

Comment: Yet, I don't recall seeing where he states how previous architectures failed to have a uniform interface between components. I've worked on many systems in which one SOAP service called upon the features of another SOAP service in order to perform its duties. I believe that's called "SOA".

Comment: Well Rest obviously shares attributes of other architecture styles etc. it's not all novel and new. Also, soap and rest are not mutually exclusive. A restful service could do so with soap (from what I understand). I think the uniform interface though, is unique in that it is a constraint, a requirement of rest, unlike other architectural styles. What I believe he means is "don't martial data to other interfaces, use the same interface for all participating components."

Comment: Most SOAP services missed HATEOAS.  They all missed Identifications of resources.  You always had to invoke methods on remote objects in SOAP to retrieve anything. You never retrieved them directly.  Self messaging was not possible, the WSDL was always needed.  That's not to say WSDLs were bad or hard to use...they just broke a constraint of a "Uniform Interface"

Comment: @ChrisDaMour - isn't the WSDL an interface standard in itself? i.e. a WSDL is written according to a standard, and therefore a client can read it to understand the actions available on the server. Therefore there is no coupling... The server provides a WSDL at an expected endpoint, and the client can therefore couple with the server. Why is this not a uniform interface?

Comment: Because the result of the soap action isn’t another wsdl like thing that can be acted upon. Also all implementations of soap clients I’m familiar with don’t retrieve the wsdl at runtime, instead they do it at client time.  I could probably be convinced this is a limitation of client implementation , but This is inherently unrestful, triggered by the fact that soap actions return static messages and not resources with further hypermedia controls.  A lot of “rest” clients do this to, jump to known urls instead of discovering actions from a root resource at runtime

Answer (score 3):

Your question is somewhat broad, you seem to be asking for a restatement of the definitions you have. Are you looking for examples or do you not understand somethings specifically stated.

I agree that the line:

> These URI's are going to look like each other

is fundamentally wrong.  URIs needn't look anything like each other for the Uniform interface constraint to be met.  What needs to be present is a uniform way to discover the URIs that identify the resources.  This uniform way is unique to each message type, and there must be some agreed upon format.  For example in HTML one document resource links to another via a simple tag:

```
<a href="URI of related resource" rel="defined relationship">fallback relationship</a>
```

HTTP servers return html as a text/html resource type which browsers have an agreed upon way of parsing.  The anchor tag is the hypermedia control (HATEOAS) that has the unique identifier for the related resource.

The only point that wasn't covered was manipulation.  HTML has another awesome example of this, the form tag:

```
<form action="URI" method="verb">
  <input name=""></input>
</form>
```

again, browser know how to interpret this meta information to define a representation of the resource acted upon at the URI.  Unfortunately HTML only lets you GET and POST for verbs...

more commonly in a JOSN based service, when you retrieve a Person resource, it's easy to manipulate that representation and then PUT or PATCH it right back to it's canonical URL.  No pre-existing knowledge of the resource is needed to modify it.  Now when we write client code we get all wrapped up with the idea that we do in fact need to know the shape before we consume it...but that really is just to make our parsers efficient and easy.  We could make parsers that analyze the semantic meaning of each part of a resource and modify it by interpreting the intent of the modification.  IE: a command of make the person 10 years older would parse the resource looking for the age, identify the age, and then add 10 years to that value, then send that resource back to the server.  Is it easier to have code that expects the age to be at a JSON path of $.age?  absolutely...but it's not specifically necessary.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm don't quite understand what you mean though. What is the "interface" that needs to be uniform? I was thinking that it was the protocol, i.e. http. But it sounds like you are saying that also the responses must be uniform, i.e. an agreed upon information representation format. But "uniform interface between components" sounds to me like it's just the protocol that needs to be uniform. What do you think?

Comment: i think you are hearing "uniform interface" and thinking an interface that's uniform.  He just used the term "uniform interface" as a grouping concept of the 4 sub constraints: Identification of resources, Manipulation of resources through these representations, Self-descriptive messages, HATEOAS.  Anything that follows the 4 constraints is a "uniform interface".  Don't break the term apart for analysis, just accept it as is. HTTP is a good component of implementation because it has URLs and hyper text baked in