# How REST API works?

Tags: api, rest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26qQc.png)

What this picture actually describes?
I have a confusion, which is, whenever we are sending a GET request to the server via a API,
are we sending it in JSON format ?Or, in HTML or any simple Text format?

On the other hand, whenever the API is sending a request (HTTP verb actually) to the server, is it using HTTP format? and the server also returns a response in HTTP format or in JSON format?

I know this question is very silly....but I am very new in API world.

Answer (score 0):

The picture is not accurate, the server sends a response and the MIME type does not matter, it can be even RDF n-triples or images depending on the type of the service and what it supports. The protocol is always HTTP, though theoretically it is possible to use a different protocol. REST has some mandatory constraints, you can read about them in the [Fielding dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) or I wrote about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25706876/607033) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26049761/607033).